# htaccess rule giving 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am getting errors when I am trying to rewrite URL.

From this:

```
www.example.com/products/product-details.php?alias=abc-def-123
```

To this:

```
www.example.com/products/abc-def-123
```

Here is my .htaccess file

```
#Turn Rewrite Engine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ products/product-details.php?alias=$1 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

I am hitting this URL:

```
www.example.com/products/abc-def-123
```

Update:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please confirm if you are hitting `www.example.com/products/product-details.php?alias=abc-def-123` link in browser?

Comment: Yes, it does not occur any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah!!!!!!!
I solved my problem myself and also I want to thanks @RavinderSingh13 to make effort.

**Here is the whole .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://example.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^products/([^/\.]+)?$ products/product-details.php?alias=$1 [NC,L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following rules. Please make sure to keep your htaccess in your root folder along with your products folder(not inside it).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://example.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/products/.*\?alias=(\S+)\s
RewriteRule ^ /products/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/?$ products/product-details.php?alias=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did not make any difference. Still getting 500 Internal server error

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA, please confirm path of your htaccess file and your php file?

Comment: I have confirmed that the .htaccess file is located in root dir i.e. in the example folder. Also, other rewrite rules are working but this one is not working. Please solve my problem

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA, please do mention 2 things, 1- what is url you are hitting sample one? 2- do you have other rules apart from my posted ones? Please confirm in these and I will take a look in morning as it's late night in here.

Comment: I have answered your requirement by adding more details to ques.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA, Ok, I have updated rules now, check it once.

Comment: Now the page is working but displays no data found because no data is fetched from the database. I tried to find out request URL using print_r($_GET); for your code but it is showing '[alias] => product-details.php' instead of '[alias] => abc-def-123'

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA, ok, this assumes that your php file is present in `/root/products/product-details.php` and your htaccess is present in `/root/`? I also changed `RewriteBase` now, please do change edited rules and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Now other pages are not working because you have changed the RewriteBase, and I am not able to fetch the pages. 500 Error occurs

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA, Ok, I have changed rewritebase back to `/` now. But rules looks good to me for your product one, may be check your php code if you are expecting only 1 parameter to be passed? Because rule will send only 1 parameter in it.

Comment: RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/?$ here parameter is fetched i.e, product-details.php instead of abc-def-123.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA, no it should get whatever comes after `products` eg: out of `products/abc-def-ghi` it should get `abc-def-hi` part.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA, yes sir it's doing that only as per rules it's working fine when I tested them in my local Apache.

Comment: I got it what is the problem. Listen, when the product-details.php file is in root directory then all rules work fine, rewrite also and alias value is abc-def-123. But when I move the product-details.php file in products folder "/root/products/product-details.php", then the problem occurs and the alias value becomes "product-details.php". This is the main problem. Now solve it please. See the image above

Comment: One more update when I try to remove product-details from URL then also alias becomes product-details.php whether it is in root directory or not.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA, cool good to know, please DO NOT update your question, rather UPDATE my answer with your answer(add your answer below my solution), which will help future users.

Comment: Thanks, see 3 images above. hope it will help you in finding a solution.

Comment: @PRASHANTVERMA, I appreciate your gesture of helping here. But question section is for question section, you could edit my answer which is near to yours, that will really help future users, cheers buddy.